# Error in "asking for a library"

Tags: discussion

I asked a question specifying my -special- needs and got *off-topic* response so are there any places (forums etc) where I am allowed to ask this and get a -relatively- quick response?

Comment: You can ask for software/library recommendations on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: From Meta.Programmers.SE (which has the same close reason of asking for a library): [Why was my question closed as off topic for asking for a library?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6487/)

Comment: Go search on [meta.se] for "software recommendations" and see the rich history of this policy.  I'd normally downvote, but there's a chance that you searched here first before asking and found nothing, due to the recent split of meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

[Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) exists for this purpose.